# iPad not charging

Tags: ipad

I have reviewed the comments already posted about an unresponsive screen on my iPad air.

I have tried the following:

- Turned itself off and won't turn back on
- Been on charge for an hour still no response. The charger is working fine.
- Done a soft reset by holding down the keys

Still nothing, any ideas?

Comment: Can you please add a link to the question you are referring to here? Also, is your problem that the iPad doesn't charged (as in the title) or that the screen doesn't respond (as the text implies)?

Answer (score 1):

You could check the lightning port for dust and try clearing it out (carefully!) with a needle or air compressor. I have had this problem a few times before and fixed it this way.

Comment: Hi Lion thankyou for that I will try it. I have also noticed the following. It seems to charge ok but when I open an app the screen goes black and either doesn't come back on or the apple icon appears and it restarts. Sometimes this is immediately or I have to wait an hour or so. At no point does it feel hot. I have done a reset but it's not helped